# Convert a jpeg image series into vti image file

Tags: c#, vtk, 3d-modelling

I'm using VTK API in my C# application. Please can someone explain how to convert my image series which is in .jpeg format to .vti image file to be able to use it in my application? The image series contains sequential abdomen images. Quick reply will be most appropriated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can read each image in the series using:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/JPEGReader

Then, you could combine them into a 3D image manually:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/ImageData/IterateImageData

Or more automatically with:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/CombiningRGBChannels