# Format of .VTI ( VTK)

Tags: vtk

Any one know , what is the format of .vti . This type of files are used to store series of image data (structured way to store data) . By knowing the format it would be easy to implement by my own. ( Store multiple images into this file for further processing for reconstruction).

Problem is this type of files are stores data in Binary format.

Any help should be appreciated....

Do not mark it as duplicate ( [Convert a jpeg image series into vti image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102681/convert-a-jpeg-image-series-into-vti-image-file)) this question is totally different..)

Answer (score 3):

.vti, as any other format from VTK are open format. See their specification here.
https://vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf

**ImageData**

EachImageData piece specifies its extent within the dataset’s whole extent. The points and cells are described implicitly by the extent, origin, and spacing. Note that the origin and spacing are constant across all pieces, so they are specified as attributes of the ImageData XML element as follows.

```
<VTKFile type=”ImageData” ...>
  <ImageData WholeExtent=”x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2”
        Origin=”x0 y0 z0” Spacing=”dx dy dz”>
    <Piece Extent=”x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2”>
      <PointData>...</PointData>
      <CellData>...</CellData>
    </Piece>
  </ImageData>
</VTKFile>
```

Comment: I already look into that pdf there is no such thing which briefs about .vti file format..

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but if possible provide a sample example which is in text format not in binary , to actually understand , what "Piece Extent, pointData  ,cellData"  is ??

Comment: They are dozens .vti example around there, and you can produce one with ParaView quite easily. In any case, here is one. https://ufile.io/suc3yxhe

Comment: Thanks for this,
But example that you provided contains two large blocks,
both of them having same structure , I mean 6 columns, 
( Does it means x y z xn yn zn ) or some thing else???

Comment: No idea what you mean, just open the dataset with ParaView and explore it there.